# Cannot dynamically update the Vimeo player with video url in Angular

Tags: angular, vimeo

Using the Vimeo SDK (https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed) I have added the Vimeo player to my Angular (8) component. The videos URL comes in through an @Input() from my parent component.

It works just fine on initial load.

When I select another video in the list - which is a separate component - it updates the `@Input() videoUrl` with the updated Url for the selected video.

However, despite updating the `@Input() videoUrl` correctly I cannot dynamically update the Vimeo Player `options.url`.

I have tried two things:

1/ Change detection. I can click on a new video in my list and console log out the new video URL @Input() just fine. I use this URL to update my Vimeo player `options.url`, however the HTML element doesn't update with the new video.

2/ I have also tried binding my @Input() videoUrl to the div element, again this doesn't update the players url.

**video.component.ts**

`import Player from '@vimeo/player';`

```
@Input() videoUrl: string;

videoPlayer: Player;
options = {
  url: this.videoUrl,
  width: 800
};

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.videoPlayer = new Player('vimeo-player', this.options);
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.options.url = changes.videoUrl.currentValue;
}
```

**video.component.html**

`<div id="vimeo-player"></div>`

Note that I have also tried dynamically updating the template:

`<div id="vimeo-player" [attr.data-vimeo-url]="videoUrl"></div>`

I expect that the Vimeo player updates its videoUrl options dynamically with @Input() value I provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vimeo SDK is just JavaScript, not Angular, so it is not hooked into Angular's update cycle. I think you will need to call the [vimeo play loadVideo method](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#about-player-methods)

Something like this

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    // probably need to get the videoId from the url

    player.loadVideo(videoId).then(function(id) {
      // The new video is loaded
    }).catch(function(error) {
      switch (error.name) {
          case 'TypeError':
              // The ID isn't a number
              break;

          case 'PasswordError':
              // The video is password-protected
              break;

          case 'PrivacyError':
              // The video is private
              break;

          default:
              // Some other error occurred
              break;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you didn't extracted the video id from the url, this can help you.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.vimeoPlayer();
}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.vimeoplayer();
}
vimeoPlayer() {
  if (this.player) {
    this.player.destroy();
  }
  this.player = new Player(this.vimeoContainerElement.nativeElement, {
    url: this.vimeoVideoURL
  });
}
```